# Point-free style in Template Haskell

Tags: haskell, template-haskell, tacit-programming, pointfree

Consider the following Template Haskell function:

```
composeQ :: ExpQ -> ExpQ -> ExpQ
composeQ = \x y -> [| $(x) . $(y) |]
```

Is it possible to eliminate the lambda expression from the right hand side of the equation and write `composeQ` using point-free style?

Answer (score 4):

There's no generic way to splice expressions into any quotation in point-free style, but this particular case could be implemented like this:

```
composeQ :: ExpQ -> ExpQ -> ExpQ
composeQ = flip infixApp [|(.)|]
```

Here were flip [`infixApp`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/template-haskell/latest/doc/html/Language-Haskell-TH-Lib.html#v%3ainfixApp) which usually takes parameters in the order `left op right` into `op left right` and then supply it with the composition operator. Now we have a point-free function that's equivalent to the original `composeQ`.